# No Difference for t-test with Standardized Values

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, spss, data-transformation, standardization

I have a dataset where I am looking at two different flowers with different heights. I have standardized the height and are doing a t-test to see if there is a difference in means for the two flowers in terms of heights.

When I do the t-test for the standardized heights (as opposed to the original height in the data) I still get the same t-statistic and p-value. I'm pretty sure this is what should be happening but would like an explanation as to why this occurs.

Comment: The t statistic uses the sample  standard deviation in the denominator.  So if you standardize by dividing the heights by the sample deviation you get the same t statistic.

Comment: Thank you - so would it probably be explained by the first two formulas on this website: http://www.statisticshowto.com/standardized-test-statistic/

Comment: I think they are referring to standardized test statistics and not standardized observations.  But the form of the one sample t statistic should give you the idea.

Comment: Thank you - sorry, also to understand a bit better could I please get an explanation of the difference between the "sample standard deviation" and "sample deviation" in your first comment? Thanks

Comment: The population standard deviation is an unknown quantity while the sample standard deviation is an estimate of it. In your post $\sigma$ is used to denote the population standard deviation while s denotes the sample standard deviation.

Comment: Thank you, so when the heights are standardized the t-statistic is found by dividing by the population standard deviation (σ), but for not standardized values the t-statistic is found by dividing by the sample standard deviation (s). Sorry if I have misunderstood this

Comment: If you standardize your samples by subtracting the sample means and dividing by the standard deviations, you'll have two new samples each with mean 0. Naturally you won't find a difference since you just made their means exactly the same.

Comment: Thank you - I think I understand. To find standardized values we use the first formula on this: http://www.statisticshowto.com/standardized-values-examples/ The sample mean,population mean, sample standard deviation and sample size which are needed for the t-statistic (the T-score (single population) formula here: http://www.statisticshowto.com/standardized-test-statistic/ ) is therefore the same and therefore t-statistic is same for standardized scores and non standardized scores. Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what should be happening. When you standardize (z-score) the flower heights, you are just doing a linear transformation of the data.

Imagine I had Group 1 with scores 8, 10, and 12 and Group 2 with scores 4, 6, and 8. The means for Group 1 and Group 2 are 10 and 6, respectively. So the mean difference you would be testing with a t-test is 4 (i.e., 10 - 6).

But what would happen if you subtracted 4 from every score? Group 1 and Group 2 means are now 6 and 2, respectively, but the mean difference you would be testing is the same: 4. So the t-test would show the exact same result.

Now, when you z-score (standardize) a variable, all you are doing is taking the raw score, subtracting the mean of the raw scores from it, and then dividing by the standard deviation of the raw scores. Just like above, the mean difference is preserved. You know you are doing a linear transformation because the correlation between raw and standardized scores is 1. Here's some R code showing that:

```
set.seed(1838) # Setting seed for replicability
raw <- rnorm(100,mean=10,sd=4) # Creating raw scores
z <- scale(raw) # Standardizing scores
cor(raw,z) # Looking at correlation between the two
plot(raw,z) # Plotting values
```

The correlation is 1, and the plot looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this great and detailed answer (and sorry that I only saw it now). This is on the lines of what I was thinking and you have confirmed it for me perfectly!!

Comment: But what if I am testing multiple hypotheses, for example, if all the coefficients are 0. Will standardising affect it as well?